# JS insertBefore of different elements inside loop : some are done in the next loop call

Tags: javascript, loops, appendchild

I have a list of canvas and I want to move some of them by an offset, using a loop of insertBefore.

Here is my loop, selectedMarkers are indices of canvases I want to move :

```
            for (let i = 0, l = this.selectedMarkers.length; i < l; i++) {
                this.markerMoving(this.selectedMarkers[i], this.selectedMarkers[i] + moveOffset);
            }
```

The function markerMoving contains this (markerRenderingElements is the list of canvases:

```
    [...]
    workspace.insertBefore(markerRenderingElements[oldMarkerNumber], markerRenderingElements[newMarkerNumber + 1]);
    [...]
```

The browser console shows me that insertBefore is called correctly for all elements, but in fact, here is what happens...
Let's say I wanted to move 3 elements : e1 e2 e3

1st call of loop : only e3 moves, e1 and e2 stay static.

2nd call of loop : e3 and e2 move, e1 stays static.

3rd call of loop and other calls : all are moving.

It seems that until all elements have not moved independently, they won't move together and I don't understand this behavior: why aren't the other insertBefore taken into account? The problem is that, due to this behavior, the elements aren't moved where they should be.

Comment: This seems easy enough to make a simple example, so please provide that. Just strip out all the functionality unrelated to this and try to provide a snippet that shows this result.